# If not... followed by function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement

I am stuck with this question. I am not too concerned about what each function does, but more importantly how does the IF statement work with functions. From my understanding, the IF.... or statements usually work with a condition, but for this scenario it only involves two functions without any conditions?

```
def disk_check_usage(disk):
    du = shutil.disk_usage(disk)
    free = du.free/du.total * 100
    return free > 20 

def check_cpu_usage():
    usage = psutil.cpu_percent(1)
    return usage < 75 


if not disk_check_usage("/") or not check_cpu_usage():
    print("ERROR!")
else: 
    print("Everything is OK")
```

I want it to give an 'Error!' message when both conditions (free > 20 and usage < 75) are not True/Satisfied.

Edit: When I run the code, 'free' = 17 which gives 'False' and Usage < 75 which gives 'True'. So my IF statement would mean 'If not False or not True:'. What does that mean and how does the system whether to run 'if' or 'else' statement?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: functions, when called evaluate to a value. `if` can check using values. (because conditions *also* resolve to a value, if you notice).

Comment: When evaluating the expressions the functions are called and replaced by their return value.

Comment: Does your code work as it should? (The type of answer that you get may depend on that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From my understanding, the IF.... or statements usually work with a
>   condition, but for this scenario it only involves two functions
>   without any conditions?

There's always a condition. The code you posted is no exception.
What you call a "condition" is really just a boolean expression in a specific context. If the entire expression evaluates to `True`, you enter the body of the if-statement. Otherwise, if it evaluates to `False`, you don't.

**Example**

The following code iterates over the characters in a string, and only prints characters which are both alphabetic and uppercase:

```
string = "Hell2O]WoR3(Ld"

for char in string:
    if char.isalpha() and char.isupper():
        print(char)
```

Output:

```
H
O
W
R
L
>>>
```

`str.isalpha` returns a boolean - `True` if the string (in this case a string consisting of a single character) contains only alphabetic characters, `False` otherwise.

`str.isupper` returns a boolean - `True` if the string (again, just a single character in this case) contains only uppercase characters, `False` otherwise.

I picked these two string methods to simulate the two functions you have in your code, since they also return booleans.

Let's take the first character, `"H"`:

```
>>> char = "H"
>>> char.isalpha()
True
>>> char.isupper()
True
>>> char.isalpha() and char.isupper()
True
>>>
```

You see, the entire boolean expression `char.isalpha() and char.isupper()` evaluates to `True`. In order for the entire expression to be evaluated, both functions need to be called - you can think of their return values effectively "replacing" their respective function calls. When `char` is `"H"`, after calling the functions, the expression really looks like this:

`True and True`

Which evaluates to `True`, so we enter the body of the if-statement.

In your case, you used `or` instead of `and`. What I said about boolean expressions collapsing down into a single `True` or `False` value still applies, the only difference would be in short-circuiting, which isn't that relevant to your question I think.

**Example**

Here's something closer to what you have. Imagine a scenario where you want to monitor the temperature and radiation of something. If either the temperature OR the radiation levels are not nominal, we trigger an alarm.

```
def is_temperature_nominal(temp):
    return 70 <= temp <= 100

def is_radiation_nominal(rad):
    return rad < 200

if not is_temperature_nominal(250) or not is_radiation_nominal(50):
    print("Alarm triggered!")
else:
    print("Everything is good.")
```

Output:

```
Alarm triggered!
>>>
```

I picked the nominal ranges arbitrarily, and I picked the arguments `250` and `50` arbitrarily as well. With these two hardcoded values, the boolean expression would look like this after calling the two functions:

`not False or not True`

Which is another way of saying:

`True or False`

With an `or`, only one of the operands has to be `True` in order for the entire expression to evaluate to `True` - therefore the entire expression evaluates to `True`, and we enter the body of the if-statement, triggering the alarm (because only one of the values needs to be not nominal in order for the alarm to trigger. If both values are not nominal it would also trigger the alarm. The only way we enter the body of the `else` is if both values are nominal).

Answer (score 1):

They are some operations you can do with booleans.

In particular, (not a) or (not b) is equivalent to not(a and b); at least one of the two have to be False

You just have to inverse your tow statements: if everything is ok, print ok else print error

```
if disk_check_usage("/") and check_cpu_usage():
    print("Everything is OK")
else: 
    print("Error")
```

Answer (score 0):

> From my understanding, the IF.... or statements usually work with a
>   condition, but for this scenario it only involves two functions
>   without any conditions

`if` (as well as `while`) needs an expression that evaluates to a logical (type `bool`) value (either `True` or `False`), or can be typecast to a logical value (for example `None` is typecast to `False`).

In your case, the conditions (namely, comparisons) are done **inside** your functions (see the `return` statements), so that the functions already return logical values.

Comment: Hey there, 

When I run the code, 'free' = 17 which gives 'False' and Usage < 75 which gives 'True'. So my IF statement would mean 'If not False or not True:'. 

What does that mean and how does the system whether to run 'if' or 'else' statement?

Comment: Erm, that's basics of logic: `not False` is `True`, `not True` is `False`, `False or True` is `True`. So your `if` fires, and `print("ERROR!")` is executed.

Answer (score -1):

When calling a method, it's executed and return a value, which can be use in different manner : directly or stored in a variable, this code is exactly the same as the following, but just not saving in variables and inline the methods in the condition

```
disck_check = disk_check_usage("/") # True or False
cpu_check = check_cpu_usage() # True or False

if not disk_check or not cpu_check: # Boolean conbination
    print("ERROR!")
else: 
    print("Everything is OK")
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to use 'and' operator instead the 'or' used by you.

```
def disk_check_usage(disk):
    du = shutil.disk_usage(disk)
    free = du.free/du.total * 100
    return free > 20 

def check_cpu_usage():
    usage = psutil.cpu_percent(1)
    return usage < 75 


if not disk_check_usage("/") and not check_cpu_usage():
    print("ERROR!")
else: 
    print("Everything is OK")
```